# Angularjs isReady event needed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

Does anyone know of an "all is done" event in angularjs?
I have tried using `$viewContentLoaded` event  but it fires before the `ng-repeats` finish.
The `angular.element(document).ready`  not even firing,
and when i use Directives it's even worse.

just need a bit dom manipulation..

Help!!

10x

Answer (score 0):

Write the below code outside the controller and check.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    var appElement = document.querySelector('[ng-app=wlccApp]');
    var appScope = angular.element(appElement).scope();
    var controllerScope = appScope.$$childHead;
    alert('hi')
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks.
i get an error:
Microsoft JScript runtime error: [ng:btstrpd] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.22/ng/btstrpd?p0=document

Comment: @jinji Please check with the updated code for me it is working, i am getting the alert message

Comment: Hi @sameer, thank you very much.
i do get the alert, but the dom is not ready when i get it.
the ajax calls not done and the ng-repeat still running

Comment: Call the particular method in [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

Comment: sorry man, i didn't get it, what does ng-init got to do with it?